# Who saved the open net goal against the matchup with the warriors?

Tags: plot-explanation, d3-the-mighty-ducks

In [D3: The Mighty Ducks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D3%3a_The_Mighty_Ducks), the mighty ducks face off with the Edan Hall Warriors varsity team. The winner of this game gets to stay and the losers leave. As the final game is being played, the ducks are faced with trouble early as their goalie is taken out of position to leave the Warriors with an open net attempt. Which Mighty Duck player skates around the net and leaps in front of the goal to save the puck from going in? Charlie Conway? Or Adam Banks?

Answer (score 1):

Adam Banks is the one who dives in front of the net when Julie "The Cat" Gaffney is out of position from saving an earlier shot. He stops the puck from going into the goal with his chest.

Happens 1 hour and 36 minutes into the movie.

You can see it's Adam as the player has the #99 jersey.

https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Adam_Banks

> Adam’s jersey is numbered #9 when he played for the Hawks but when he later joined the Ducks an extra 9 was added to his jersey making him #99.

[image: Adam Banks diving in front of the net to save a goal]

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain (though it's been a while since I've seen the movie) that it was Charlie, having fully embraced the new coach's mantra of two-way hockey. I will double-check when I get home.

Comment: It’s not Charlie because Charlie had the C captain tag on him, and the person who blocked the puck clearly doesn’t. I think it Adam Banks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was Banks. Whoever said Charlie is wrong. You can clearly see it's him through the visor as well as his jersey number #99. That's actually how Charlie got the breakaway with Goldberg as Banks had to take the dive to stop the puck so he was a bit late catching up to them when they pressed forward on the offensive.